# Git doesn't find repository

Tags: linux, git, version-control, ubuntu, gitosis

I have a git repository setup on a server:

```
andy@ubuntu:/home/git/repositories$ ls
gitosis-admin.git GoGoFlow.git
andy@ubuntu:/home/git/repositories$ pwd
/home/git/repositories
```

All fine and dandy.

I then come to a new machine - which I have not used before with git **I manually added my machines public key into the export_dir/keydir in the gitosis project**

and type:

```
git clone git@novo.dyndns.tv:GoGoFlow
Cloning into GoGoFlow...
git@novo.dyndns.tv password:<passwd>
fatal: GoGoFlow.git does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Have I missed a setup step in my new git installation **windows 7**?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "manually added my machine's public key", I assume you mean directly in the gitosis installation. That doesn't work. You have to administer gitosis through a clone of the gitosis-admin project. The gitosis installation walks you through getting this set up. Also, I recommend [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) over gitosis. Ubuntu has gitolite available as an apt package.